# How to move scrollview with button

Tags: android, scrollview

I want to create an Android Application that use scrollView, but i don't want to scroll it with drag on the screen, but i want to scroll it with a button. my first question is how to disable all of touch on the scrollView, so it won't scroll when user touch on it?

and the second how to scrool with a button? for the second question, i try to use scrollTo() method. so this is my code on the button

```
    public void UpCLick(View view){
           currentY=currentY - 1;
                   vertScroll.scrollTo(currentX,currentY);
     }

    public void DownCLick(View view){
           currentY=currentY + 1;
                   vertScroll.scrollTo(currentX,currentY);

     }
```

but it always get stopped. FYI currentX, and currentY is an Integer variable.

Answer (score 1):

extend ScrollView and override onTouchEvent() in ScrollView. don't call super method in it.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     // super.onTouchEvent(event); // don't do this
     return true;
}
```

and use ScrollView.scrollBy(int,int) method for scrolling.